# List Button Not redirecting to the record using Visual FLow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I am trying to redirect user to a record using Lightning Component which is used inside Visual FLow.

I have created list button and calling this flow from that button.

I followed this post [Flow redirect to created case](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pSM2QAM) to create flow and button .

Which has package on this link :- https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t90000000kcsu

Everything works fine when flow is invoked from Flow component added on Layout or a Quick Action of Type Flow is used.

Basically I have created a screen flow which has two screens and when user hit Next I have another screen where I have added Lightning Component which has event to redirect to new record.

Flow Defination.
[image]

I have list button when clicked opens up following flow screen.
[image]

When entered value and hit next , Ideally it should redirect to the new case record but it shows a blank screen.

[image]

I am not able to figure out what goes wrong when flow is invoked through list button.

Can any one please advise is there something special we need to do while invoking flow from list button and redirect it to new record. Wondering what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you try debugging the Lightning component controller by adding `debugger;` in the `init` method? I guess the event `e.force:navigateToSObject` with slideDevName `related` only works for components that are added on record detail pages. Might have to use `lightning:navigation` or `window` methods in that case.

Comment: I did try with that but no luck !